# django ajax doesn't save form to database

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, django-3.0

I have a problem when i try to save data to database using ajax.

It always gives me `success` .. and that means it works fine .. But it didn't save data to database.

and also i tried to print `'message': 'form is saved'` in `console.log(data.message)` but it always gives me `undefined`

**Views**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def PostCreateView (request):
    form = PostCreateForm()
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = PostCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            data = {
                'message': 'form is saved'
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "blog/new_post.html", context)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('new_post/', PostCreateView, name='new_post'),
```

**new_post.html**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="my-ajax-form" data-url="{% url 'new_post' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <input class="btn btn-secondary mt-4" type="submit" value="Add New Post">
</form>
```

**plugins.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $myForm = $('.my-ajax-form'); // select form class
    $myForm.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $formData = $myForm.serialize(); // get all data from form which will be submitted to database
        var $thisURL = $myForm.attr('data-url') || window.location.href; // data-url is attribute in form
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url: $thisURL,
            data: $formData,
            success: handleSuccess,
            error: handleError,
        });
        function handleSuccess(data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data.message);
            $myForm[0].reset();
        }
        function handleError(ThrowError) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(ThrowError);
        }
    });
});
```

I tried tonnage of questions and answers here .. without a result for two days.

any body can help please ?

Thanks in-advance

Comment: First, can you show your _forms.py_. Also, have you tried printing the value of `instance` after submitting. Why do you have two form variables? Try to put only one there. Add `form = PostCreateForm(request.POST)` outside the `is_ajax` if statement

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this,
PostCreateForm() is an object you're instantiating. But you're passing a comparison of variables.

In the end you only get True, False or None as the argument being passed to `PostCreateForm()`
 The python interpreter might be evaluating them as comparisons.
Which means You might possibly end up with a function  call like this `PostCreateForm(True,None).`

Comment: i understood you points, you are write .. i changed it to `PostCreateForm()` and `PostCreateForm(request.POST)` .. thanks .. and i am still waiting to solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

form = PostCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

Answer (score 0):

I have not much experience with Ajax using forms but I think you are not using your sent data (data : $formData) in your view to get data using Ajax. You are just validation it like normal one. Please refer this article 
https://dev.to/coderasha/how-to-send-django-form-with-ajax-4bpo